# Bash command in a variable without executing

Tags: linux, bash

I have two commands which I want to close in variables:

```
val=`awk -F "\"" '{print $2}' ~/.cache/wal/colors-wal-dwm.h | sed -n -e 1,3p -e 5,7p`
dummy=`printf "dwm.normfgcolor:\ndwm.normbgcolor:\ndwm.normbordercolor:\ndwm.selfgcolor:\ndwm.selbgcolor:\ndwm.selbordercolor:")`
```

They basically print some stuff. I want to merge the output with **paste** command (this doesn't work):

```
paste <($dummy) <($val)
```

I wanted to avoid temp files but at this point I'm out of ideas. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> $dummy
> ```

Is a variable, not a command to execute. `echo` is a command. `printf` is another command.

```
paste <(echo "$dummy") <(echo "$val")
```

Do not use backticks - `$(..)` instead. Check your scripts with shellcheck. You code is somewhat unreadable to me... if you don't care about variables, just don't use them.

```
awk -F '"' '{print $2}' ~/.cache/wal/colors-wal-dwm.h |
sed -n -e 1,3p -e 5,7p |
paste <(
     printf "dwm.%s:\n" \
        "normfgcolor" \
        "normbgcolor" \
        "normbordercolor" \
        "selfgcolor" \
        "selbgcolor" \
        "selbordercolor"
  ) -
```